# Screen update with SwiftUI and Core Data mirroring CloudKit

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I'm having issues getting a view to update when new information is synced via cloudkit. While running this app on two devices, if device A adds a palette, it will only appear on device B when the app is restarted. I've looked at some other answers on stack overflow but none have worked. Does anyone have any idea?

Here is my persistent container from AppDeligate

```
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Swatch")

        // get the store description
        guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
            fatalError("Could not retrieve a persistent store description.")
        }

        // initialize the CloudKit schema
        let id = "iCloud.com.peterfoxflick.swatch"
        let options = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: id)
        description.cloudKitContainerOptions = options
        
        let remoteChangeKey = "NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationOptionKey"
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber,
                                   forKey: remoteChangeKey)
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        
        return container
    }()
```

And my view

```
struct PalettesListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var palettesList: PalettesListViewModel
    
    let pub = NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationOptionKey"))


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                    ForEach(self.palettesList.palettes){ p in
                            Text(p.name)
                                .font(.headline)
                         
                    }

                }
            }
            .onReceive(pub) { (output) in
                self.palettesList.fetch()
      }
}

struct SwatchesListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PalettesListView()
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding the same listener to my ViewModel but had no luck with that. If you would like to see all the code you can take a [look at GitHub](https://github.com/peterfoxflick/swatch).

PS. Some of the brackets/formatting might be off, I cut down the code to just the relevant portions.

Answer (score 1):

Your merge policy is making local changes Trump remote ones. Try removing that or using a different merge policy.